# Linear Independence of Angles Corresponding to Primes $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$

Tags: number-theory, complex-numbers, prime-numbers

Any prime $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ can be written uniquely as the sum of two squares $p = a^2 + b^2$. In the complex plane, this corresponds to the 8 Gaussian integers with norm $p$. We can write these points as
$$
\sqrt{p}e^{2\pi i (\pm\Phi + t/4)}
$$
where we define $\Phi$ as the argument of the point in the first octant ($\Phi = \arg(a+bi)$ where $a^2 + b^2 = p$ and $a \geq b$) and $t \in \{0,1,2,3\}$ corresponds to multiplication by a unit.

I want to show that any finite set of the type $\left\{ 1, p_1, \ldots , p_N \right\}$ where $p_j \equiv 1 \mod 4$, $j = 1, \cdots, N$ is linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$. In other words, we want to show
$$
\sum_{j=1}^{N} \alpha_j \Phi_j + \alpha_0 = 0
\iff
\alpha_0 = \alpha_1 = \cdots =\alpha_N = 0
$$
where the $\Phi_j$ is defined for each $p_j$ as described above.

I encountered this problem while self-studying some number theory and have been stuck for a bit. I'd appreciate some hints! The approach I tried is to go by contradiction and try to show that something will contradict the definition of a prime number, but I think I've gotten lost!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a previous answer here from @TheoBendit (I suppose he deleted it) but that was enough when combined with a hint from Ramin Takloo-Bighash to help me solve this.

Since we can multiply through by a common denominator, we can assume all the $\alpha_j$ are integers.

Let $a_j + ib_j = \sqrt{p_j}e^{2\pi i \Phi_j}$ (These coefficients come from $p_j = a_j^2 + b_j^2$) Suppose the angles are linearly dependent, then we can calculate
\begin{align*}
\prod_{j=1}^{n} (a_j + ib_j)^{2\alpha_j}
&=
\prod_{j=1}^{n} \left(\sqrt{p_j} e^{2\pi i \Phi_j} \right)^{2\alpha_j} \\
&=
\prod_{j=1}^{n} p_j^{\alpha_j} e^{2\pi i (-2\alpha_0)} \\
&=
\prod_{j=1}^{n} p_j^{\alpha_j} \\
&=
\prod_{j=1}^{n} (a_j + ib_j)^{\alpha_j} (a_j - ib_j)^{\alpha_j}
\end{align*}
Cancelling terms from both sides, we have
\begin{align*}
\prod_{j=1}^{n} (a_j + ib_j)^{\alpha_j}
=
\prod_{j=1}^{n} (a_j - ib_j)^{\alpha_j}
\end{align*}
This is a contradiction since $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a UFD.

Credit to Theo for motivating me to consider a product of this type, and credit to Ramin for the hint of raising everything to the $2\alpha_j$.

Comment: Ring theory is not my field, so I'm not sure if this is a problem, but why does this equation contradict $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ being a UFD? These factors aren't necessarily prime, are they?

Comment: First, I suggest you stick to $\alpha_j\in\mathbb{Z}$, otherwise you could be into trouble (the equality $(z_1z_2)^\alpha=z_1^\alpha z_2^\alpha$ is false if $\alpha$ is not a rational integer in general), and moreover if $\alpha_0\in\mathbb{Q}$ you cannot obtain the third equality... but you can always multiply the dependence relation by a common denominator. Second, in your last product, it is $\alpha_j$ instead of $\alpha$. Finally, you don't  get indeed a contradiction, What you get is $\prod_{j=1}^n (a_j-i b_j)^{\alpha_j}$, is a real number, and that's all.

Comment: UFDs have uniqueness only up to associates.  I’m not sure you’re contradicting that here.

Comment: @TheoBendit the terms $a_j + ib_j$ are indeed gaussian primes since each of the $p_j \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.

Comment: @GreginGre I mention in the second paragraph that we can multiply through by a common denominator. Thank you for pointing out the typo, I have corrected it. 

Lastly, I believe the contradiction still holds since given the explicit information we have about $a_j$ and $b_j$ it can not be a real number.

Comment: @Randall I have added some more details to the answer, I hope it is more clear where the contradiction comes from now.